# Adding too many Points to DataPoint

Tags: c#, winforms, class, buffer, mschart

I'm creating objects of a the class AddGraph and hosts. In my class PingForm, with the method AddNewHost(...) like this

```
public void AddNewHost(HostPinger host)
{
    HostOptions dlg = new HostOptions();
    if (dlg.ShowDialog(this, host) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        bool exists = false;
        lock (_hosts)
        {
            foreach (HostPinger hp in _hosts)
            {
                if (hp.HostIP != null && hp.HostIP == dlg.Host.HostIP)
                {
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            hostListPanels.Add(Convert.ToString(dlg.Host.HostIP));                   


            source.AddGraph newGraph = new source.AddGraph();
            graphList.Add(newGraph);

            var createdPanel = newGraph.panelAdd(tableLayoutPanel1, Convert.ToString(dlg.Host.HostIP), hScrollBar1);

        }

        dlg.Host.Logger = DefaultLogger.Instance;
        dlg.Host.OnPing += new OnPingDelegate(OnHostPing);
        dlg.Host.OnStopPinging += new OnHostPingerCommandDelegate(hp_OnStopPinging);
        dlg.Host.OnStartPinging += new OnHostPingerCommandDelegate(hp_OnStartPinging);


        ...          
    }
}
```

After every Ping another method gets called in PingForm Class, void OnHostPing(). Now in OnHostPing() I'm calling PlotData(), this method is also in PingForm.

```
public void PlotData(Chart chart)
{
    unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    double rvalue = R.Next(0, 20);

    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new NetPinger.source.AddGraph.ReturnChartDelegate(PlotData), new Object[] { chart });
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (graphList[i].Name != chart.Name)
        {
            for (int x = 0; graphList[x].Name != chart.Name; x++)
            {
                i = x;
            }
            graphList[i].dataBuffer(unixTimestamp, rvalue);
        }
        else
        {
            graphList[i].dataBuffer(unixTimestamp, rvalue);
        }                          
    }
}
```

After I created multiple Hosts, each of them has his own panel with a graph inside. Every graph is filling his own values, that is working. But if I try to fill the buffers for every AddGraph Object separate, it's not working, the timestamps and values of all Objects are written in all buffers together. So lets say I've got timestamp / value for host1: 19991 / 10, host2: 1999 / 12 in the buffer there will be both values of host1 and of host2 but I want an own buffer for each AddGraph Object. The buffer looks like this and is inside the AddGraph Class:

```
public void dataBuffer(double unixTimestamp, double roundTripTime)
{
    if(counter != graphDataPoints.Length)
    {

            graphDataPoints[counter] = new DataPoint(unixTimestamp, roundTripTime);
            counter++;

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("buffer full.");
    }
}
```

That's what data inside the buffer looks like after running some pings.
[image: Buffer]

But as seen in the UI each chart has its own data added to the chart and not both as in the buffer. I'm adding the data to the chart with `chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(unixTimestamp, rvalue);` in the plotdata method.

[image: gui]

I hope it's somehow understandable what my problem is and what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for help!

Comment: What are you targetting and what Chart class do you use? Winforms, WPF, ASP..?  MSChart?
Always __TAG__ your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW thanks for information! I added better tags

Comment: Hm, hard to tell. Could be a concurreny issue; you don't create the random R multiple times, right?

Comment: @TaW no im not creating random R multiple times. I've added some pictures for better understanding of the problem!

Comment: Could it be that you make a mistake in assigning the buffer? A common error is assuming an asignment will copy the data when it just creates a new reference. The remedy then is to enforce a copy by e.g. a ToList() call or ToArray()..

Comment: @TaW so you mean first assigning the data to an array or list and than to the buffer?

Comment: How many buffers do you have? One for each chart or only one in total? And: How exactly are the points added to the Charts? Note: DataPoint is a class, ie a reference variable!

Comment: @TaW so i've got in the class AddGraph one public DataPoint[] graphDataPoints = new DataPoint[50] as the buffer, but for each object out of the AddGraph Class that I create, the object will have its own DataPoint[] or are they shared among all the objects? The points are currently directly added after every ping with AddXY(unixTimestamp, rvalue) but the goal later should be to fill the charts from the buffer. but currently my buffer isn't working properly

Comment: _for each object out of the AddGraph Class that I create, the object will have its own DataPoint[]_ Ok, but how is that array filled? By asssigning the buffer or by assigning a copy of the buffer?? if the buffer is aBuff and you want to have its points in bBuf do you write: `bBuf = aBuf` ? Instead you need: `bBuf = aBuf.ToArray()`, which will create a copy.

Comment: In that case they all share the same buffer data. And if you clear one all get cleared. Common mistake, took me quite a while when it first hit me when starting with List<T>. But you still are storing the values in DataPoint objects and these also are reference variables, which may or may not cause similar problems..Make sure to clear the array after copying the points! (Btw I almost never use arrays and always try to use List<T> instead..)